# htaccess rewrite parameters in address bar when page is refreshed after session timeout

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my htaccess setup to redirect all paths through a variable called pages

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?pages=$1 [L]
```

This works just fine and if you go to the url  www.mydomain.com/path/to/file I get the desired result of having the variable pages = "path/to/file".

I cant quite pinpoint exactly when the problem occurs(but it seems to be when the session times out, it does not occur if you refresh without being idle) and then you refresh the page the address bar reads www.mydomain.com?pages=path/to/file.

The page still works, but it gives an ugly URL.  Is this normal? Is there anything that can be done to stop this from happening?

Thanks.

Here is the Full htaccess:

```
### HABARI START
RewriteEngine On

### turn off directory browsing
Options -Indexes

## redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

## map any path that is not an actual folder to the pages param
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite everything else through the pages parameter 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?pages=$1 [L] 

### HABARI END
```

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: How do you generate urls for links and redirects? Is it used consistently everywhere?

Comment: urls are always generated in the /path/to/file format.

Comment: It might be you use `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` somewhere.

Comment: Marek, it doesn't occur unless the page is idle for a while, and then the page browser is refreshed, this is never an issue when a link is followed. I only use chrome, so this may be browser specific.?

Comment: @DavidStetler `.htaccess` doesn't play a role here, there's no way it can rewrite your nice url back to the ugly one. You should really look if there's some condition in your code where you redirect to current url, which is however constructed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right under the www redirect rule, add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?:index\.php|)\?pages=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: verbatim?  what is {THE_REQUEST} ?

Comment: @DavidStetler yes, [%{THE_REQUEST}](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) is the first line of an HTTP request, e.g.: `GET /blah?param=var HTTP/1.1`

Comment: the page is actually redirected to index.php?pages=/path/to/file,  So I want to match the index.php? part.  Can you help me write the rule for that so I dont screw it up, thanks